# MapView being shrunken when adding buttons to a MapView fragment

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-layout, mapfragment

I am trying to create a Map App that allows you to switch between map and satellite view using two buttons. However, when I add the two buttons the map is being shrunk down to not take up the full screen of the device.

[Shrunken Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1yhH.png)

How can I make it so that the map takes up the entire screen, and then the buttons are below that screen when you scroll down? Here is the code for the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:uiZoomControls="true"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />


   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Map View"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Satellite View"/>

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

hello try FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout

```
<ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          map:uiZoomControls="true"
          tools:context=".MapsActivity" />


   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Map View"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Satellite View"/>

    </LinearLayout>

 </FrameLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this simple layout, I don't see why you need scrollView, you can just use [constarintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Fragments.MenusDesign.ExpandableCategoriesMenu.ExpandableCategoriesMenu">


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    map:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    map:uiZoomControls="true"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Map View"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Satellite View"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>
```